# User without permission can click on the "check approval button", which leads to an error

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, approval, sitepages

I have set up my page library so that only the author and user with approval rights can view drafts.
So now I create a new page as normal user and click on the button "Send for approval". Then I get the button "Check approval".

I shouldn't be allowed to see this button without the specific permission.
When I click on this button I get the following error message:

Inner-Message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) Exception-Message: [HTTP]:500 - Internal Server Error [CorrelationId]:335f369f-90d1-9000-9d52-b50139fb13ba [Version]:16.0.0.19729

How do I prevent unauthorized users from seeing and clicking this button by mistake?

Comment: Unfortunately, currently the best answer to this is Tell your users not to click that button.

Comment: How can Microsoft ignore such an obvious bug... wtf

Comment: Whether you use Microsoft Flow to approve the modern page? Per my test, there is no "Check approval" button appearing after I click "submit for approval". You can provide some detailed steps and screenshots with us.

Comment: @Hellofiona_MSFT, no OP is referring to the built-in content approval that can be turned on in list settings.

Comment: Yes that's right, I'm using the built-in feature (library settings > Version management settings > Content approval required for sent items? = Yes)

Comment: I have access to three different organization's SharePoint Online tenants, and can confirm this behavior in all of them.  There is already a uservoice submission covering this that you can vote for:  https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/36618994-hide-approval-button-for-users-without-approve-per